# drupal_set_message($node->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value']); what does this statement mean

Tags: php, drupal

How to get information about a node i.e its content type its all field etc using drupal_set_message? Also what is the meaning of ['und'][0]['value'] in this statement? drupal_set_message($node->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value']);

Answer (score 2):

`drupal_set_message` will set a message which reflects the status of the performed operation. If the function is called with no arguments, this function returns all set messages without clearing them.

Parameters

`$message`: The message should begin with a capital letter and always ends with a period '.'.

`$type`: The type of the message. One of the following values are possible:

```
'status'
'warning'
'error'
```

`$repeat`: If this is FALSE and the message is already set, then the message won't be repeated.

According to your code

`$node->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value']` should contain the message you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

1/ as Dasun wrote `drupal_set_message` will display the string you passed as the `$message` parameter to the user.

If you want to output an entire node, for debugging for instance, you'd better use the `devel` module and its helper functions. `dpm` will pretty print the node to the message area, i.e.

```
dpm( $node );
```

See http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7 for more info.

2/ 'und' has to do with the multi-language support baked into D7. It is an abbreviation for 'undefined'. Since a field can have multiple values it contains an array and that array can contain an array with multiple keys. The default key used in fields is 'value'.

So if you'd have a multi-value field with a value for Spanish and a key 'target_id' and you wish to you get the second value, you'd do it like this:

`[ 'es' ][ 1 ][ 'target_id' ]`